# replacing quote in php

Tags: php

I want to replace `“` and `”` characters with the caharacter `"` in php . I have written as follow but it doesn't change. How can I do this ?

```
$temp=str_replace("”","\"",$temp);
$temp=str_replace("“","\"",$temp);
```

Comment: Instead of escaping the characters you can put them between single quotes. Like so '"'. That might be easier to understand and less error prone. For as far I can see your code should work. You could also do it with arrays instead of calling the function twice. See the documentation on mixed types.

Comment: works for me http://codepad.org/kjrBsTz0

Comment: Your input and your source code is probably not encoded with the same character set, str_replace works with the bytes coming from the source code. Can you tell us more about your input?

Comment: Try replacing `&#8220;` and `&#8221;` too.

Comment: I am reading the text from text file

Comment: So please check the encoding of your test file and of your source code file. Does it work, if you copy some of the text directly into your php-file?

Comment: yes it works in my php file but not working when reading from the text file.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
<?php

    //left double quote 
         $temp = str_replace("&ldquo;","\"",$temp);
         $temp = str_replace("&#8220;","\"",$temp);

        //right double quote 
         $temp = str_replace("&#8221;","\"",$temp);
         $temp = str_replace("&rdquo;","\"",$temp);
    ?>
```

Comment: This will be more safer to use.

Answer (score 0):

This working fine . Tested

```
$temp = "I want to replace “ and ” characters with the caharacter";
$temp=str_replace("”",'"',$temp);
$temp=str_replace("“",'"',$temp);
echo $temp;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
I want to replace " and " characters with the caharacter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $temp=str_replace('“',' ',$temp);
    $temp=str_replace('"',' ',$temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the encoding of your source code file and of your HTTP connection. If this doesn't match, the replace will probably fail.

I suggest ensuring both is UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

try this way..

```
$temp=str_replace('”','"',$temp);
$temp=str_replace('“','"',$temp);
```

if not work use this

```
$temp=str_replace('&ldquo;','"',$temp);
$temp=str_replace('&rdquo;','"',$temp);
```